# Android build failed after Ionic Native Crop plugin installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I’m using Ionic 3 and trying to use the [Ionic Native Crop plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/crop/) on my app, but without success.

Before the plugin installation all works fine when I run `ionic cordova run android --device`, but, when I install the plugin with (as shown on the plugin page):

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crop
```

and

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/crop
```

the following error occurs when I run `ionic cordova run android --device`:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>     FAILED
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1 mins 15.829 secs
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --device (exit code 1).

If I uninstall the plugin, all works fine again.

`ionic info` output:

> cli packages: (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 5.0.1 ios 4.5.4
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Node : v6.11.2
> npm  : 3.10.10
> OS   : Windows 10
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : C:\Android\android-sdk
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

Do I have to search for another plugin or is there some way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing the plugin. and use it like

```
plugins.crop(function success () {

}, function fail () {

}, '/path/to/image', options)
```

or, if you are running on an environment that supports Promises (Crosswalk, Android >= KitKat, iOS >= 8)

```
plugins.crop.promise('/path/to/image', options)
.then(function success (newPath) {

})
.catch(function fail (err) {

})
```

then try

```
cordova clean android
cordova build android
cordova run android
```